# SwiftUI - Force automatic title display mode in just one view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I have two views, both with their NavigationStack like this:

**First View Code:**

```
NavigationStack{

   VStack{

       NavigationLink{
         SecondView()
       }label:{
         \\some code here
       }

   }
   .navigationTitle("Title")
   .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
}
```

**Second View Code:**

```
NavigationStack{

   VStack{
     //some other code here
   }
   .navigationTitle("Title 2")
   .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
}
```

Everything works fine but I'd love to force the SecondView title mode only to .automatic.
As things are right now, when I navigate from the FirstView to the SecondView, the title mode of this last one is also set to ".inline".

I'd love to have the title set to ".inline" only for the FirstView.

Is there a way to achieve this in SwiftUI?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `.large` ?

Comment: "the title mode of this last one is also set to `.inline`" Yeah, you told it to choose *automatically*, so choosing to use `.inline` is definitely possible. If you don't want it to choose automatically, make a choice yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.automatic` will use the display mode of the previous view on the stack. Only when there is no previous view does it default to `.large` when there is a title and `.inline` when there is no title. See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbartitledisplaymode/automatic).

If you want the large title display mode then you need to explicitly use `.large` for your second view.